# Is there someway to disable all firebase logging to console?

Tags: javascript, logging, firebase

I have created some unit tests for my firebase security rules. Part of this testing is trying to do illegal operations and asserting that they fail.

My problem has to do with noise; when I run the tests using nodeunit, the firebase client spits out several logs similar to this:

> FIREBASE WARNING: set at /user failed: permission_denied

I do not want this output when intentionally doing illegal operations as it just results in noise and confusion.

Comment: OP: Please change accepted answer to be @peter hayman's.  As he points out, `firebase.setLogLevel()` is now a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days there is an option to set the log level on the global `firebase` object:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

firebase.setLogLevel('silent')
```

Answer (score 3):

In our testing suite, we rewrite process.stderr.write to only ignore firebase warnings like so:

**Javascript**

```js
process.stderr.write = (function(write) {
  return function() {
    if (!arguments[0].includes("FIREBASE WARNING"))
      write.apply(process.stderr, arguments);
  };
}(process.stderr.write));
```

**Typescript (including tslint fix)**

```js
process.stderr.write = (() => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unbound-method
    const write = process.stderr.write;

    return function () {
        if (!(arguments[0] as string).includes("FIREBASE WARNING")) {
            return write.apply(process.stderr, arguments);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I'd suggest if you're using Jasmine then place this in a helper file so that it's called automatically prior to the tests running.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to disable the security warnings as they are emitted asynchronously by the Firebase SDK. I worked around this by adding a message before the errors:

```
>>> An intentional security error should be printed after this line...
```

Comment: would really like to have a less "chatty" version of the sdk.  it really pollutes testing output.

Comment: testing of security rules is on the road map, ideally they would be done by something more sophisticated than trying to write test units.

Comment: that would be great.  However, it'd still be nice to have a less chatty sdk.  I'm working on using Mocha for e2e testing as well.  Less noise in the output would be great.

Comment: @Kato +1 for being able to disable noisy output. We are testing our security rules and would rather not have to see all the warnings.

Comment: @Kato things have gotten way worse since your library started spitting out 10x larger warnings for permissions errors. Please, give us a way to stop the mess!

Comment: 2 years later and this is still an issue!

Answer (score 2):

As Kato said, there doesn't appear to be an official way to disable it. That said, if you really want to, it takes 2 seconds to go into the source, Ctrl+F for "WARNING", and comment out this line:

```
"undefined"!==typeof console.warn?console.warn(b):console.log(b)
```

Comment: Depending on *how* you're testing, it may be even easier to just add this line to the beginning of your test suite (assuming it's JS): `console.warn = function(str){}` to override `console.warn`. I'm using VowsJS and it makes the output clean.