# Firebase warning: Using an unspecified index

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I get this warning message from Firebase for every single `orderByChild` I used in my queries from JavaScript:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "" at /tables to your security rules for better performance

So far my queries ran quite fast so I think it is not necessary to include the `indexOn`. Just wondering what are the negative impacts?

Also, how do I actually disable the warnings as they are quite irritating when I am debugging.

Comment: Be aware that without an index, **all** of the data under the queried key is downloaded and is filtered **on the client**.

Comment: @cartant I see I see. So basically the indexing is some sort like the rules at firebase site? I need not to change anything at the client site right?

Comment: Yes. The answer below has a link to the docs that explain how to specify an index in the security rules. There is no client-side config that relates to indices.

Comment: @cartant I see I see, at first I was afraid that in order for indexing, I might need to restructure my entire database or re-code everything from scratch. Now that I know that it is just some rules to be specified at the firebase website rather than client site, am I right? Thanks so much!

Comment: @cartant I just added in "indexOn" : ["whatever the warning message told me to add like eg. email, address"] at the firebase site. What it does anyway?

Answer (score 15):

If you are on development phase, you won't feel the difference. But as your data grows indexing helps making your queries much faster.

Read this to know more on advantages of indexing.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

As far as I know to disable the warnings, you have to edit firebase source code.
[Is there someway to disable all firebase logging to console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060924/is-there-someway-to-disable-all-firebase-logging-to-console)

Comment: how can I actually write the indexing? From JavaScript when I insert new records or just a simple rule at the firebase site? Because my codes are quite complex, I am afraid if I have to add in the indexing, it may actually affect the performance.

Comment: You have to just add a child`".indexOn': '<your_search_key>'` on your firebase rules. Don't have to modify any of your existing codes.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data This doc have enough examples to help you to write your own indexing rule.

Comment: Hey do you mind to take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263533/firebase-indexon-warning-message

Comment: Yes, I have answered it. Please check it out. :)

Answer (score 13):

Firebase provides powerful tools for ordering and querying your data. Indexing can improve the performance of our queries. consider a table called `dinosaur` has some data like:

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "height" : 2.1,
    "length" : 12.5,
    "weight": 5000
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 2500
  }
}
```

You need to (search) order the dinosaurs height, and length, but never by weight. so you need to set a rules for `dinosaur` table like:

```
"rules": {
  "dinosaurs": {
    ".indexOn": ["height", "length"]
  }
}
```

By telling Firebase this information, Firebase can use this `.indexOn` to optimize our queries for height and length. Then we maintained Firebase security for querying our data and improve the performance of our queries as well.

Comment: What happend if you ask an orderBy with weight ?

Comment: You have full freedom to order your data. if you want your data order by weight then set `".indexOn": ["weight"]`
firebase tells which you to wants and which you don't want. it's about you. indexing is very useful when querying your data

Answer (score 8):

As the others have said: if you don't define an index, all filtering happens client-side. This is likely fine during initial development, but as you add more data it becomes more and more wasteful.

To fix the problem, define the correct index in your Firebase Database rules. You can modify the rules in the [Database panel in your project's Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/rules). See [defining data indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#defining_data_indexes) in the Firebase documentation.

> Is there any way for me to observe what has changed through the indexing?

1. After you define the correct index, the warning will disappear from your JavaScript console.
2. In addition you can watch the traffic between the Firebase client and the server in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. Before you define the correct index, you'll see that the Firebase client downloads all data in the location (since it performs the filtering locally). After you define the correct index, you'll see that the Firebase client only downloads the data that matching the query.

Comment: Hey sorry but please correct me if I am wrong. Let's say I got 100 users records, then I want to get certain user detail based on email using orderByChild. So without indexing, basically the client side will download all 100 user records, then perform the filter at client side. But with indexing, the moment I pass the email parameter to firebase, the firebase back end will actually perform a filter, and return the matching user back to the client. Is that correct?