# Firebase IndexOn Warning Message

Tags: javascript, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some question regarding the indexing of firebase. Here is my firebase structure:

```
merchants {
    merchantID1 : {
        merchantName : 
        branches : {
            branchID1 : {
                branchAddress :
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My indexing rule at firebase site:

```
"merchants": {
      ".indexOn": ["merchantName"]
},
```

I got two different orderByChild query from JavaScript. One is querying `merchantName`, the other is `branchAddress`. After I added in the `indexOn merchantName rule` at firebase, the warning message disappeared. However, when I perform another function which is querying the `branchAddress`, I am getting this warning message:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": 
"branchAddress" at /merchants/-KpeV5_lnWA2Zd_g7x8C/branches to your security 
rules for better performance
```

How can I actually specify the indexOn rule at different level of a child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$childKey` matches any child key. So you have to use that concept here.

Change your db rule to:

```
"merchants": {
    ".indexOn": ["merchantName"],
    "$merchantId": {/*This matches all keys*/
        "branches": {
            ".indexOn": ["branchAddress"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see I see. Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Hey sorry just a quick check with you regarding the firebase rule. Normally why developer write those ".validate" rule at the firebase site since the validations should be done at the client site before posting to the database site? Is there a reason to write those ".validate" rule at the firebase site? Is it because sometimes when we post data to database site, there are chanced that the data might get corrupted, that's why we should perform another check before inserting?

Comment: I would say client side validations are just for best user experience and server side validations are to check for proper data, before storage. So I think you should have proper `.validate` keys on your security rules.

Comment: @AnandMohan i'm doing the same but getting same error why.?

Comment: Share your db structure and db rule.