# firebase indexOn for child values

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get all post with mood equal to M1 using firebase Query like below:

```
db.ref(`Recommendations`).orderByChild(`post/vote/moodTags/${idMood}/key`).equalTo(`${idMood}`).once('value').then(recs =>{
        //Número de recs con el mood
        let recsCount = recs.numChildren();
        console.log(`Número de recs encontradas --> ${recsCount}`);
        ...
    });
```

and firebase console show warning:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "post/vote/moodTags/M1/key" at /Recommendations to your security rules for better performance.

but, my indexing rule at firebase site is:

```
"Recommendations":{
  ".indexOn": ["post/userFirebaseKey","post/user/firebaseKey","userFrom/firebaseKey","post/location/placeId","firebaseKey","placeId"],
  "post":{
    "vote":{
      "moodTags":{
        "$moodId":{
          ".indexOn": "key"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so, how can I actually specify the indexOn rule when i use a child level?

my db:

```
+ Recommendations
  + idRec
    property1:''
    property2:''
    property3:''
    + post
      property21:''
      ...
      + vote
        + moodTags
          + M1
            key:'M1'
            name:''
            url:''
          + M2        
            ...
```

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251328/firebase-warning-using-an-unspecified-index

Comment: @valhallarossferrer It is not enough, the documentation is very simple and trivial. What I need is a little different. that's why I put the rule that I have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be operating a level too deep there: After all you want to index the *list of moodTags*, and not the contents of *one* moodTag.

That means your rules would have to look more like this:

```
"Recommendations":{
   ".indexOn": ["post/userFirebaseKey","post/user/firebaseKey","userFrom/firebaseKey","post/location/placeId","firebaseKey","placeId"],
  "post":{
    "vote":{
      "moodTags":{
          ".indexOn": "key"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can read up on these indexing rules in [the official Google Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data?), also in [this helpful article on Medium](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-security-rules-88d94606ce4a) and in [this Google Groups post where someone had a similar issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/firebase-talk/m3k51DOyfrs).